# How use custom merge function for two observables

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android, rx-java2

I have two observables emitting the same data type. I need to merge them

```
    Single<Post.List> postsRecent = getRecentPosts()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
    Single<Post.List> postsPopular = getPopularPosts()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
```

Now I need to merge this two observables into single one, however I don't need to have both arrays to be merged I need to use custom function to merge them, for example I want to exclude duplicate posts having the same id

Is it possible to achieve this using RxJava ?

Thanks

Comment: it is possible, but is `Post.List` a custom data structure? Actually, if you could include some of your `Post` class, I could give you a better suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to make some assumptions here since you have yet to post your `Post` implementation. Let's assume we have a list of posts : `List<Post>`.

If you want to do all the dirty merge work yourself, you can simply use `Single.zip(...)`

```
Single.zip(getRecentPosts(), 
           getPopularPosts(),
           (posts1, posts2) -> myCustomMergeMethod(posts1, posts2))
      .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
      .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
```

---

It's not clear exactly what you want to do with your custom merge... However, you can almost always do all the work with rx transformations:

```
 getRecentPosts().mergeWith(getPopularPosts())
            .flatMapIterable(posts -> posts)
            .distinct(post -> post.getId())
            .toList()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
```

The above will do some of what you were asking for:

1. merge the streams using `mergeWith(...)`
2. transform a list emission into *n* `Post` emissions using `flatMapIterable(...)`
3. filter out any duplicate ids using `distinct(...)`
4. collect the entire stream and emit it as a single list using `toList()`

You can continue to transform your list many more times until you get what you wanted.